# Suggestion for a camera

Tags: computer-vision, cameras

Are there good low cost cameras that are frequently used in robotics?

I am assuming there are cameras that are good fit for robotics ...

1. Works well with OpenCV
2. PC Windows support - USB2/USB3 (GigE, USB3 vision cameras seem pricey)
3. Good image sensing performance
4. Adjustable focus - manual or motorized (fine focus control would be great)

Do IP cameras make good cameras for Robotic vision projects?

Comment: I think the best camera is webcam. Cheap, easy to reach and there is many examples. You can modify it easily with no worry

Comment: what is the target application?

Comment: I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: I understand that. I wasn't asking about a recommendation for a brand or particular model, I am interesting in the type most people generally use.

Comment: IP cameras, webcams, Raspberry Pi cams are all great cheap ans be suitable for most hobby robotics projects

Answer (score 1):

I personally love the ZED as I do a lot of work with stereo vision and come with opencv modules built for them, but they are quite pricy, I find that most higher end webcams work great with openCV, IP cams are a poor choice in my experience with unpredictable latency (you may not care about this), built in compression which can mess with openCV and they are much more expensive than a comparable webcam.